# Can I loop through files using file matching patterns in azure-pipeline.yml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I know I can loop trough arrays in yaml:

```
steps:
- ${{ each var in split(variables.vars, ', ') }}:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ var}}
    displayName: Printing ${{ var }}
```

and that Azure pipelines supports files matching patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

How do I combine those together so that I run `dotnet build` script for each `**/*.csproj` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such method can use the file matching patterns in the each expression to loop over files.

The each expression will be expanded and looped at compile time.

File matching patterns need to be used during the running of the agent job to match files in the Pipeline task(Runtime).

Refer to this doc: [File matching patterns reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops)

> File and directory names are compared to patterns to include (or sometimes exclude) them in a task.

Therefore, each expression doesn't support using file matching patterns.

If you want to do matching in yaml pipeline, you need to manually define all csproj file paths in Pipeline variable before the Pipeline is running.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a variable, which is only available at runtime, you could specify an object, which is available at compile-time.

```yaml
# pipeline.yml
trigger: none

steps:
- template: build-projects.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
    - src/project1
    - src/project2
    - scr/project3
```

```yaml
# build-projects.yml
parameters:
- name: projects
  type: object

steps:
- ${{ each project in projects }}:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build ${{ project }}'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: **/*.csproj
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}'
```

Comment: Sure, but I want to use wildcards,resp file matching pattern and loop trough the files. Here the matching is done by DotNetCoreCLI task internally,not by yaml

Comment: And that's because the repo is checked out and the task can iterate over the files. The pipeline engine can only work with the yaml files that are referenced in the pipeline.